# Solving multiple $L_1$ penalties with quadratic programming

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

Starting from a simple $L_1$ penalization:
\begin{equation} min_x \frac{1}{2}||y-x||^2_2 + \lambda||Dx||_1 \end{equation}
We can solve this with quadratic programming via the dual problem:
\begin{equation}
min_z \frac{1}{2} z^\intercal D D^\intercal z - y^\intercal D^\intercal z \\
u.c. -\lambda\mathbf{1} \leq z \leq \lambda\mathbf{1}
\end{equation}
and the final solution reads $ x = y - D^\intercal z$

Now let's assume I add a second $L_1$ penalty term:
\begin{equation} min_x \frac{1}{2}||y-x||^2_2 + \lambda_1||D_1x||_1 + \lambda_2||D_2x||_1 \end{equation}
I'd assume the formulation doesn't change much, and the dual problem is similar using $D = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
D_1\\ D_2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and $\lambda = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

$D_1$ and $D_2$ are pretty well behaved. $D_1$ is a first-difference matrix and $D_2$ is a second-difference matrix.
$$ D_1 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
  0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
D_2 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
  0 & 1 & -2 & 1 &\cdots \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

The issue is that I find $D D^\intercal$ to be singular, so the quadratic program can't be solved.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I would better use a second order conic formulation. Even if slightly boring, duality calculation are fairly easy (see http://blog.mosek.com/2014/03/how-to-write-dual-problem-in-nutshell.html). Defining $\lambda_2 = \lambda_2 \mathbb{1}$ $\lambda_1 = \lambda_1 \mathbb{1}$ your problem reads

$ \min t + \lambda_1^T w_1 + \lambda_2^T w_2$

$ s.t. $

$ r = y -x $

$(1,t, r) \in Q_r$

$ z_1 = D_1 x, z_2= D_2=x$

$ (w_{ij} , z_{ij})\in Q^2,\quad i\in\{1,2\}, j=1,\ldots$

where $Q^2$ is the ice-cream cone and $Q_r$ is the rotated one. The dual problem is, if I am not mistaken, the following

$ \max \mu_0 + y^t \mu_r$

$ s.t. $

$ \lambda_1 \geq \mu_1 $

$ \lambda_2 \geq \mu_2 $

$(1,-\mu_0, -\mu_r) \in Q_r$

$ D_1^T \mu_1 + D_2^T \mu_2 + \mu_r\leq 0$

That should be solvable by any conic quadratic solver (as MOSEK...but you see I am biased...look at my nickname...) or recast in a QP form.